# Is it necessary to pass 'self’ to args when using theading.Thread or multiprocessing.Process with a class method

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

Using threading or multiprocessing with a class method, for example

```
class ExampleClass:
    def run(self, run_param):
        print run_param

    def run_parallel(self, num):
        processes = []
        for i in xrange(num):
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.run, args=(i,))
            # should I pass self to args like
            # p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.run, args=(self, i))
            processes.append(p)
        for p in processes:
            p.start()
        for p in processes:
            p.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are passing `self.run` as a bound method, you do not need to pass `self` to it as the first argument:

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.run, args=(i,))
```

`self` would only be needed if you pass an unbound method to `Process` as the `target` parameter:

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=ExampleClass.run, args=(self, i))
```